# How to - write a program that runs and gives preset answers to voice commands

Tags: python, ios, speech-recognition, voice-control

I was hoping someone would help me out with a good starting approach for what I think would be a simple program to write using python or another language that can handle voice commands and/or speech recognition efficiently

Basically, how I envisioned the program was it would run on my iPhone or iPad, and with speech recognition, it would listen for a specific request, maybe a keyword like “shop 1” and it would respond with answers that I preset when I writing the program.

For example - “hey what products belong in (“keyword”)

and the response would be:

“as of now, you have products a,b,c planned to go in that location”

I have been learning python for about a year now and a few other languages, and although I have yet to write a complex program from scratch on my own, lately I have been feeling comfortable enough to start practicing but I am having trouble knowing the best ways to approach a program since I assume everyone has their own best practices they stick to.  Thanks in advance for your help and sorry if I sound like I don’t know what I am talking about lol

Comment: Take a look at: https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-speech-to-text-with-python-3df0d973b426

Write a simple program that takes inputs from Microphone or an existing audio file and prints the text. Once you're able to get the text, use it to perform your search operation, etc., prepare the output and then use a text-to-speech module in python to convert it into audio - something like:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-text-speech-python/

Comment: Yes ! This approach is definitely a great place to start for my program, seems fairly simple and straightforward that if I can successfully build my program , later I can explore ways to approach it with a more sophisticated method